# Sockets: Client can't send message to server even when the connection is established

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server class which listening to new connections:

```
public class Server{
public static void main(String[] args){
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
System.out.println(" Listening for connections");
String typeOfConnection;
Socket s = null;
try {
      // socket object to receive incoming client requests
      s = ss.accept();


      // obtaining input and out streams
      ObjectInputStream dis = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
      ObjectOutputStream dos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

      typeOfConnection = dis.readUTF();   //Read a message with the type of client that wants to connect (publisher or subscriber)
      System.out.println(typeOfConnection);
}
}
}
```

And a client class which connects to the server and sends a String.

```
public class Client{
    public static void main(String[] args){
         InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("//myIp")
         Socket s = new Socket(ip, 3201)

         ObjectInputStream dis = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream())
                  ObjectOutputStream dos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream())

         dos.writeUTF("Hi");
         dos.flush();

}
```

When I run the server it starts to listening to connections and then I start the client. The connection is established normally but the String is not send.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the ObjectOutputStreams before the ObjectInputStreams.

When creating an ObjectInput- or an ObjectOutputStream a serialization stream header is read/written. Because you are creating the ObjectInputStream on both client and server before the OutputStream they both block trying to read the header, which is not available yet.